# Can not resolve 'com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory'

Tags: java, maven, jira-rest-java-api

I try to learn a lesson on the use of JIRA REST Java Client Library from this page https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Tutorial. But My IDE (Eclipse) can not find a class 'com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory'.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ru.trust.jira</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-m19</version>
</parent>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What more need to add the module to resolve the error? Where it hides the class?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial is not compatable with Jira REST Client 2.0. It is necessary to look [Migrating from JRJC 1.x to 2.x](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Migrating+from+JRJC+1.x+to+2.x)